# Inserting JSON in DataTable in Google Visualisation

Tags: gwt, google-visualization

I read that JSON can be inserted into a datatable. However, its done 
in JS on the HTML page (if memory serves right). I am using the GWT- 
visualisation driver as given [here](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted), and the only methods to add a row are not 
designed with JSON in mind. Is there any work-able solution? I am 
trying to make a Stacked Column Chart. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled with this using geomap and data table combined. In my workaround I used the evalJSON() in prototype javascript framework to make the json string an object.

```
var country_obj = country_data.evalJSON(true);
```

Then I loop over the object's length :

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addRows(country_obj.country.length);
data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
data.addColumn('number', map_context); 

var j = country_obj.country.length;
for ( i = 0; i < j; i++ )
{
    var num = new Number(country_obj.country[i].geo_mstat_reads);

    data.setValue(i, 0, country_obj.country[i].country_name);
    data.setValue(i, 1, num.valueOf());
}

// and then the table.draw() with the data
```

This worked very well for me because it scales to the exact size of the dataset you are trying to show.

Also you can do a whole whack of operations on an object which makes your life and coding easier to read and write.

I hope this helps you with your problem.

Comment: I cant do that in java, it seems.

Comment: java is to javascript what a car is to a carpet

Answer (score 1):

same pb, and don't know if it's feasible :

```
public native DataTable createDataTable(String obj) /*-{
    console.log("create Datatable :" + obj);
    var dt = new $wnd.google.visualization.DataTable(obj);
    console.log("Datatable created");
    return dt;
}-*/;
```

This create an empty dataTable whereas the JSON input is well formatted...